# Erro ao gerar Migrations EntityCore para MySQL

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Seguinte galera estou tentando usar o novo EFCore sendo que com MySQL, eu instalei os seguintes pacotes `nuget`:

> Install-Package MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore -Pre
>   Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools –Pre

utilizando o seguinte tutorial: https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/full-dotnet/new-db.html

porém quando executo o comando para adicionar a `migration` o seguinte erro ocorre:

> `Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=7.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified.  The assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but not fully signed with the correct private key. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131045)`

Já fiz esse mesmo tutorial com o `SQLServer` e o mesmo funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Veja aqui uma situação semelhante: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041051/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-mysql-data-version-6-2-2-0

Comment: Derrepente este link te ajuda.
Abraços! https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/pt-br/contents/articles/17952.entity-framework-code-first-migrations-com-mysql.aspx

Comment: Então, acabou que era um problema da versão de pre-release mesmo, felizmente não esta ocorrendo mais.
Obrigado a todos pelas respostas!